# How to alter sensitivity of Ubuntu Dock in 17.10?

Tags: 17.10, ubuntu-dock

I often need to copy-and-paste and use GUI controls on the edges of the screen.

In previous versions the Ubuntu Dock could be configured to only show when the cursor was in the corner, not just on an edge, and there was a 'sensitivity' parameter that could be set high to preventing accidental triggering of the Dock.

These don't seem to be present in the Ubuntu 17.10 Control Panel. Is there some extension or hidden configuration option in 17.10 that could:

1. make the Dock show when the cursor is in the top-left corner, rather than just on the left, and/or
2. alter the sensitivity of the Dock auto-show?

Answer (score 8):

Follow the steps below to alter the sensitivity using `dconf-editor`:

1. Select preference `org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock.pressure-threshold`.
2. Set the 'Use default value' slider to OFF.
3. Enter a custom value in the 'custom value' box. The default value is `100` and it seems like values around `500` make it a little less sensitive.

For me, a value of `1000` makes it seemingly impossible to open the Dock, so that's some evidence that the setting does seem to be doing something and is probably not just my imagination.

Comment: In 18.04 I set it to `10` to make it less sensitive.